# Get columns of a listview row

Tags: android

How can I get the columns of a listview row?

I have:
listView.getItemIdAtPosition(info.position))

This returns the position. Maybe I have to use getSelectedItem?

In my listView I have:

- _ID, Name, anotherColumn ...
- 1, name1, x...
- 2, name2, y...
- 3, name3, z...

How can I get the first column or the second? Each column is a TextView. I fill with:
new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_cadenes, mCursor, FROM, TO);

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023979/from-sqlite-onlistitemclick-nullpointerexception/14024048#14024048) post may help you in finding values from selected row of listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get the columns of a listview row?

Since you are using a SimpleCursorAdapter you can call `getCursor()` and use `moveToPosition()` to pull all of this information from the existing Cursor at any point in time.

> I have: listView.getItemIdAtPosition(info.position))
>
> This returns the position.

`getItemIdAtPosition()` should return the Primary Key `_id` which is very different from the position.

> Maybe I have to use getSelectedItem?

I would recommend using the OnItemClickListener, it is called immediately when the user touches a row and has access to the row's layout, position, and id.